# Syntax Highlighter for Twig

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting, twig

Is there any code for **Twig**?
Something similar to symfony.com .
The same style for **PHP**, **XML** or **YAML**.

Comment: You can implement santaxhighlighter into your Template
http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/

Comment: I want some similar to Symfony2 documentation

Answer (score 2):

To have it short: **Twig and Jinja share a common syntax.**

If you want to create a documentation like Symfony, this may be of interest to you as well:

https://github.com/fabpot/sphinx-php/blob/master/sensio/sphinx/configurationblock.py Seems like the parser for the symfony-documentation. Let me comment the interesting part of that here:

```
formats = {
    'html':            'HTML',
    'xml':             'XML',
    'php':             'PHP',
    'yaml':            'YAML',
    'jinja':           'Twig',
    'html+jinja':      'Twig',
    'jinja+html':      'Twig',
    'php+html':        'PHP',
    'html+php':        'PHP',
    'ini':             'INI',
    'php-annotations': 'Annotations',
}
```

Here is where it can actually be used with: https://www.sphinx-doc.org

Comment: @Tineo I think the best answer is a link to a document where Symfony explains how to contribute to their documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/documentation/format.html

Comment: i need install python on my server? =/ for use the Sphinx... well, i want to integrate with my symfony2 app